# Como checar se um valor começa com barra seguida por uma mensagem?

Tags: javascript, regex

Eu recebo um valor desta forma: `/{mensagem}` e caso fosse diferente disso (nao tivesse o `/` antes da `{mensagem)`, queria que ele me retornasse erro.

`{mensagem}` serve como variável e não pode ser alterada.

Comment: A expressão regular a ser utilizada seria semelhante a essa `/\/\w+/g.test(variavel_mensagem)`

Comment: O que significa os `{}` aqui? eles são caracteres de uma string? quer comparas o conteúdo depois da barra `/` ou somente verificar se a barra lá está?

Comment: Regex pra uma coisa dessas não faz sentido. Diria que mais da metade das soluções que pedem regex aqui do site deveriam ser resolvidas com operações simples de string.

Comment: Oi, você apagou a pergunta que tinha dado resposta. Foi algo errado na resposta? Já agora pode rever esta pergunta e as respostas e aceitar alguma caso tenha resolvido o problema.

Comment: Perdão.. mudança no projeto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parece-me qie o que quer é saber se a string começa com uma barra `/`, ou não.

Tendo uma dada *string*, para saber se ela começa com um dado caractere têm várias maneiras diferentes. Usar regex para algo tão simples não parece necessário.

#### Exemplos:

```
var str = 'string de teste';
```

- [str.charAt(index)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt)

Usando o `.charAt()` pode extrair o caractere na posição desejada.

`str.charAt(0)` dá a letra "s".

- [str.substring(inicio[, fim])](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

Usando o `.substring()` pode extrair uma parte da string, por exemplo entre a posição 0 e 1.

`str.substring(0, 1)` dá a letra "s".

- regex

Pode testar usando regex. Neste caso deve usar o simbolo de inicio de string seguido do caractere que quer. Neste caso sendo uma barra ela deve ser escapada com `\` (para não ser interpretada como fecho da regex).

`/^\//.test(str);` dá false, ou seja a *string* **não** começa com uma barra `/`

Answer (score 4):

Se as strings válidas são da forma `/{mensagem}`, com o valor da string `{mensagem}` já salvo em uma variável, *não é necessário RegEx*! :)

```
var str = "/msg válida";
var msg_valida = "msg válida";
if(str == "/" + msg_valida) console.log("Mensagem válida!");
```

Porém, se o seu objetivo original era flexibilizar um pouco o RegEx, de maneira a permitir que determinados trechos do mesmo fossem ditados por strings arbitrárias, pode utilizar a sintaxe

```
var regex = new RegExp("prefixo" + variavel + "sufixo");
```

O exemplo abaixo ilustra, de maneira didática, como utilizar esta forma de declaração de expressões regulares.

```js
// Declaração das entradas (strings) de teste:
var strs = [
    "Teste 1",
    "/Teste 2",
    "/",
    "Teste/3",
    "/msg"
];

// Variável que representa o "miolo" do RegEx. Pode utilizar sintaxe "RegExpiana", ou seja: \d, *, ...
var msg = "msg";

// Declaração do nosso objeto RegEx:
var regex = new RegExp("^\/" + msg + "$");

// Testamos entrada por entrada...
for (var i = 0; i < strs.length; i++) {
    
    // Se corresponderem à expressão regular compilada na variável "regex"...
    if(regex.test(strs[i])){
        
        // Exibimos esta entrada (que, agora sabemos, é VÁLIDA) na tela:
        document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML += "<li>" + strs[i] + "</li>";
    }
}
```

```html
<!-- O HTML serve apenas para exibir o resultado deste snippet. -->
<h2>Strings aprovadas:</h2>
<ul id="resultado"></ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Teste isso aqui;

```
/^\/\{mensagem\}$/.test('/{mensagem}') //true
```

ou

```
/^\/\{.*\}$/.test('/{aqui vem a mensagem do seu usuário}') //true
```

Caso esta mensagem possa estar em qualquer lugar dentro de uma string maior então remova o `^` do começo e o `$` do final

Caso você queira também extrair a mensagem:

```
var match = '/{aqui vem a mensagem do seu usuário}'.match(/^\/\{(.*)\}$/);

if(match) {
    console.log(match[1]); //aqui vem a mensagem do seu usuário
} else {
    //retorne o seu erro aqui
}
```

Se os `{}` forem apenas placeholders que voce utilizou, de uma olhada na resposta do @Rui Pimentel

Comment: Isso aí, @renatoargh :) formulei minha resposta como interpretação alternativa da pergunta; mas acredito que seja mais por aí, mesmo!