# Usando RegEX para pegar determinado valor

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Estou usando esta "string?" em regex `^\/(.*)\w+$` ela detecta os valores que comecem assim: `/STRINGQUALQUER` gostaria de pegar a `STRINGQUALQUER`, qual o código eu utilizo? Uso jQuery.

Comment: Como assim? O que quer dizer como "string qualquer"? O seu regex diz que o primeiro caractere é `/`, se retirar `^\/` então já não tem de começar com `/`. Mas o que quer fazer na realidade? Dê exemplos e vai ter resposta mais acertada e não precisa de fazer [perguntas parecidas](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42136/129) várias vezes...

Comment: @Sergio Boa tarde! Nao fiz perguntas parecidas haha, na outra pergunta eu precisava obter a verificação, e agora eu preciso obter um valor, sao do mesmo contexto mas seguem caminhos diferentes. ENFIM. Eu nao sei se Regex pode fazer isso, porém eu obtenho valores dessa forma `/stringqualquer`, quando falo `stringqualquer` quero dizer qualquer caractere válido, e desejo obter este valor que vem apos o `/`

Comment: Só uma dúvida. Você está tentando capturar o quê na verdade? `.*` vai capturar qualquer caractere, mas depois você tem `\w` que captura caracteres de A-Z e 0-9. `.*` já vai funcionar para o `\w`, não entendi o que é pro regex pegar.

Comment: Também não entendi como jQuery está relacionado ao problema.

Comment: @Thomas na teoria eu queria pegar qualquer caractere.

Comment: eu quero capturar o valor com jQuery.

Comment: Teria como editar a pergunta e colocar a parte do código que utiliza o regex? Vai ajudar a dar uma resposta melhor pro seu caso e pra ficar claro o uso do jQuery no problema.

Comment: @user3163662 ok! e quer só caracteres que venham de pois de uma barra `/`? E quer só apanhar strings que comecem com barra?

Comment: @user3163662 e já agora onde vai usar essa regex? num `.match()`, `.replace()` ou outro?...

Comment: Consegui resolver este problema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regex que tem agora pode ser dividida em 5 partes para perceber o que tem e como funciona:

- `^` marca o inicio da string.
- `\/` quer dizer o caractere `/`
- `(.*)` grupo de captura. Vai apanhar todos os caracteres exepto novas linhas.
- `\w+` caracteres de palavras (letras, numeros e `_`)
- `$` fim da string

Se quer apanhar o conteudo depois de `/` basta usar `\/(.*)`. Aí omite que a barra tem de estar no inicio da string mas diz à regex que tem de haver uma barra antes dos outros caracteres da string, usando `.*`.

#### Exemplo [neste link.](http://regex101.com/r/tP4vV3/1)

Answer (score 2):

Bom pelo que entendi você tem uma string `/stringqualquer` e gostaria de obter o valor de `stringqualquer` sem a `/` na frente. Correto?

Se for esse o seu problema isso deve resolver:

`[?<=\/](\w*)`

ou assim:

`\/?(\w*)`

podes testar online [aqui](http://regex101.com/).

Minha resposta foi baseada na resposta de @Renato Dinhani Conceição, que está aqui no [SO PT](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/996/renato-dinhani-concei%C3%A7%C3%A3o).

Apenas troquei a `,` por `\/?` e `([0-9]+)` por `(\w*)` para atender a sua necessidade.

Comment: Estava quase terminando de redigir minha resposta, ia sugerir o regex101 também. +1

Comment: Tente usar assim `[?<=\/](\w*)` ou `\/?(\w*)`